# What is an efficient way to exchange the order of keys in nested dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Apologies for the convoluted question title, but here's an example of what I mean.

Transform

```
mydictionary = {"OuterKey1": {"InnerKey1": "Value1", "InnerKey2": "Value2"}, 
                "OuterKey2": {"InnerKey1": "Value3", "InnerKey2": "Value4"}}
```

into

```
newdictionary = {"InnerKey1" : {"OuterKey1" : "Value1", "OuterKey2" : "Value3"},
                 "InnerKey2" : {"OuterKey1" : "Value2", "OuterKey2" : "Value4"}}
```

Notice how the association of `InnerKey,OuterKey` pair to values is preserved, but their order has simply been reversed. Where we would previously access `Value1` using `mydictionary[OuterKey][InnerKey]` we now access it using `newdictionary[InnerKey][OuterKey]`.

A direct way to achieve this would be to recreate two nested loops through the first dictionary and build the second dictionary one element at a time. 
However, I wonder if there's a cleaner / more Pythonic way to do it, such as with list comprehensions.

Update: It seems there is some confusion about the desired output. In particular, there is confusion about which value an OuterKey should map to after the tranformation.
The answer is that the former outer key (now inner key) should map to the same value that the former inner key (now outer key) mapped to.

Comment: Is `Value1` and `Value3` supposed to be in the same dictionary in your expected output? You don't seem to explain it anywhere

Comment: The same key pairs should always return the same value, so `mydictionary[key1][key2] == newdictionary[key2][key1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case I find using `setdefault` in a loop (or a `defaultdict`) much more readable then a comprehension. After all, "Readability counts...":

```
mydictionary = {"OuterKey1": {"InnerKey1": "Value1", "InnerKey2": "Value2"}, "OuterKey2": {"InnerKey1": "Value3", "InnerKey2": "Value4"}}
d = {}
for k, v in mydictionary.items():
    for ik, iv in v.items():
            d.setdefault(ik, {})[k] = iv

# result:
# d == {'InnerKey2': {'OuterKey2': 'Value4', 'OuterKey1': 'Value2'}, 'InnerKey1': {'OuterKey2': 'Value3', 'OuterKey1': 'Value1'}}
```

The same using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in mydictionary.items():
    for ik, iv in v.items():
            d[ik][k] = iv
```

Comment: nice solution. but why didn't you use defaultdict

Comment: Old habit of writing code that needs to be compatible with python 2.4... But i'll add an example using defaultdict.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
>>> mydictionary = {"OuterKey1": {"InnerKey1": "Value1", "InnerKey2": "Value2"}, 
...                 "OuterKey2": {"InnerKey1": "Value3", "InnerKey2": "Value4"}}
>>> dict([(k, dict([(k2,mydictionary[k2][k]) for k2 in mydictionary]))
...     for k  in mydictionary.values()[0]])
{'InnerKey2': {'OuterKey2': 'Value4', 'OuterKey1': 'Value2'}, 
 'InnerKey1': {'OuterKey2': 'Value3', 'OuterKey1': 'Value1'}}
```

Comment: This is the type of solution I was hoping to see, except that it assumes (my fault due to example) all inner keys will appear in all (in particular first) outer dictionaries.